# Momentjs locale - changing the week dow has unexpected results

Tags: javascript, angularjs, configuration, momentjs

I am writing a calendar with JavaScript/AngularJS 1.5.3 and MomentJS.

I need my calendar to be configurable so that it can start on any day. For example, Wed or Friday as the first day of the week.

What I did was to change the dow of the current locale:

```
    moment.updateLocale(moment.locale(), {
        week: { dow: 4 }
    });
```

However, I am seeing an issue now.

For Jan, 2018:

```
    var startOfMonthWeekNumber = moment('2018-01-01').startOf('month').week(); //this is 52
```

console.log(moment('2018-01-01').startOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD w)); //2018-01-01 52

```
    var endOfMonthWeekNumber = moment('2018-01-01').endOf('month').week(); //this is 4
```

I believe that 52 belongs to the previous year.

How can I fix this issue with moment?

Comment: don't you need [`.isoWeek();`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/iso-week/) instead of `week()`?

Comment: Then how can I make my calendar start on any day?

Comment: You can use `doy` key to customize the first week of the year, see [Changing locale globally](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/) section of the docs.

Comment: I don't want to customize the first week of the year, I want to start my calendar on Sat, Tues or whatever.